# JSON API call in an Angular service

Tags: json, typescript, angular-2+

I have followed this format in my application to call the API and get data from it:

```
getCheckoutDetails(): Observable<UserDetail> {
    let query = `7668`;
    return this.http
        .get(this.appConfig.getAPIUrl()
            + `/buy/getDetails?${query}`)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrors);
}


private extractData(res: Response) {
    let data = res.json();       
    return data.body ? data.body.message ? data.body.message : {} : {};
}

private handleErrors(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

This is sample code on one service. Now this has been followed in all services to handle data and error. When I run `gulp cpd command` to detect the duplicate code, it lists down all the files. Is there a way to handle this without duplicating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one `httpservice` and extend it in your service, for example:

HttpService:

```
export class HttpService  {
    protected userInfo:IUserModel;

    constructor(public http: Http, public user: User) {
        this.userInfo = this.user.getInfo();
    }

    /**
     * method http get
     * @param url
     * @param params
     * @returns {Http}
     */
    fetch(url, params, addData) {
        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('User-Id',  this.userInfo.id);
        headers.append('Token',  this.userInfo.accessToken);

        if(addData.accessType) {
            headers.append('Access-Type', '1');
        }

        if(addData.limit) {
            headers.append('Offset-Step',  addData.limit);
        }

        if(addData.page || addData.page === 0) {
            let count = (parseInt(addData.page )- 1) * parseInt(addData.limit);
            headers.append('Count',  count.toString());
        }

        let options = new RequestOptions(
            {
                headers: headers,
                search: params,
            });

        return this.http
            .get(
                url,
                options
            )
             .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }



    /**
     * method http post
     * @param url
     * @param data
     * @returns {Http}
     */
    send(url, data) {

        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Id':  this.userInfo.id,
            'Token':  this.userInfo.accessToken
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
             .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }

    /**
     * method http put
     * @param url
     * @param data
     * @returns {Http}
     */
    stick(url, data) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);

        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        headers.append('User-Id',  this.userInfo.id);
        headers.append('Token',  this.userInfo.accessToken);

        return this.http
            .put(url, body, {headers:headers})
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }

    /**
     * method http delete
     * @param url
     * @param params
     * @returns {Http}
     */
    remove(url, params) {
        //var data = Object.keys(params).map(function(k) {
        //    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k])
        //}).join('&');
        //url += '?' + data;

        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        headers.append('User-Id',  this.userInfo.id);
        headers.append('Token',  this.userInfo.accessToken);

        for(var i in params) {
            headers.append(i,  params[i]);
        }

        return this.http.delete(url, {headers:headers})
             .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let data = res.json();       
        return data.body ? data.body.message ? data.body.message : {} : {};
    }

    private handleErrors(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    } 

}
```

And in your child service extends by `HttpService`:

```
export class SomeService  extends HttpService {

  constructor(private urls: Urls, http: Http, user: User) {
    super(http, user);
  }

  getCheckoutDetails(data): Observable<UserDetail> {
    let query = `7668`;
    header = {};
    return  this.fetch(this.appConfig.getAPIUrl() + `/buy/getDetails?${query}`); 
  }

}
```

Maybe you need a correct `HttpService`.